# What's it worth

Tags: meaning, phrases

I found a phrase '*What's it worth?*' written after a question asking is someone is willing to do something. Am I right in thinking that it's another way of saying '*What do you have to lose?*'

Comment: What's it worth [to you to have me do x for you]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without more context, it is hard to give an exact answer, but very often, at least in British usage, if someone asks the question "What's it worth?" ("What is it worth?") directly after being requested to do something, the question means "what is it worth, to you, for me to do that?" - "What will you pay me or do for me in return if I do that for you?".

> what’s it worth (to you)? *spoken* used humorously to ask someone how
>   they will reward you if you do something for them
>
> [Longmans Dictionary](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/what-s-it-worth-to-you)

Comment: Nothing metaphorical about it, that I can see.